# Register different implementations of class

Tags: java, static, dependencies

I want to have an abstract class, say Foo, which provides a set of APIs to be implemented by subclasses. But I don't want anyone to know which is the actual instance of this subclass, only that they can be retrieved using static Foo methods. Roughly the classes would be like this:

```
class Foo {

    protected Hashtable foos = new Hashtable;

    public static Foo getFoo(String key) {
        return (Foo) foos.get(key);
    }

    public abstract void doSomething();

}

class FooA extends Foo {

    static {
        Foo.foos.put("A", new FooA());
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("A FooA instance is doing something!!");
    }

}

class FooB extends Foo {

    static {
        Foo.foos.put("B", new FooB());
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("A FooB instance is doing something!!");
    }

}
```

And the usage would be the following:

```
Foo foo = Foo.get("A");
foo.doSomething();
```

The issue with this is that, because FooA and FooB is not directly used anywhere, the classes are not loaded and the static block is not executed. I could load them explicitly in many ways, but the point is to have "unknown" multiple implementations.

Some may think the solution is to not have unknown implementations, but this is really a requirement to my problem.

Comment: Have you considered using `Class.forName` to load your subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load "unknown" registrations (of services) if they register somehow to the base class. Various runtime containers offer various ways of registering services, but the standard way available in JDK since JDK6 is to use ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class) (javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). I use this technique to implement something that I call injectable singletons (where the singleton API does not know where its actual implementation is, see http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Injected_Singleton), but the technique could be used in your example as well.

Just make sure 
META-INF/services/your.pkg.Foo 
file is in your JAR with content mentioning following two lines (can be generated using @org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider annotation, but does not have to):

```
your.pkg.FooA
your.pkg.FooB
```

and then you can use

```
for (Foo instance : ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class)) { 
    /* do something with instance of FooA and FooB */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution (depending on the complexity of the problem) it may be easier for you to use dependency injection. In this pattern, you just define implementations of your interface, and assign qualifiers to them, and then you let the DI framework "inject" actual implementations into classes which need them. Not only do client classes not know what concrete implementations they're using, they are not concerned how to get them either, which can simplify things a lot. There are a lot of such frameworks out there already (Most notable are Spring and Guice) and java 5+ has standardized set of annotations that you use to define injection rules.